# How to check for a matching string in Jinja2?

Tags: string, jinja2

The outcome for `{{shipping_address}} = {'country_code': 'NL'}`

This is my code in a template:

```
{% if 'NL' in shipping_address %}
    hello
{% else %}
    bye
{% endif %}
```

Even though `'NL'` is there in the string, it still prints `bye`. Why isn't it recognised?